# What is wrong with this clear timeout?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

It's not working for some reason (in coffeescript)

```
afunction = () ->

    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID)
    $(".x").text("#{message}").addClass("y")
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout (-> 
        $(".x").removeClass("y")
    ), 4000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`timeoutID` is a local variable, so each time you call the method, `timeoutID` starts off undefined.

Comment: This is one of those "good" traps for young players. Imagine there's no global variables - it's easy if you try ;-)

Comment: So the quick fix is to either put `timeoutID = null` outside of `aFunction` (thus moving the variable to a higher scope), or changing `timeoutID = ...` to `window.timeoutID = ...` (making it a global).